# Display pdf document from another website within a web page - security warning

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

I want to display a PDF document in a web page. I am currently using an OBJECT tag and set it this way:

```
<OBJECT id="SitePlan" data="http://path/to/sharepoint/pdf" type="application/pdf"></OBJECT>
```

I didn't use a classid as I don't mind what PDF reader is used by the client.

The thing is the document is served by a Sharepoint web service and I am getting the IE warning `"This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"` every time I load the page.
I also tried it in Firefox and I did not get a similar warning, instead I was asked to authenticate with my domain credentials. After doing that, everything went fine.

Can anyone suggest anything that will prevent the above behaviour?

I would like to be able to display the PDF document as a subsection within the page and would rather implement something on the server side to prevent the security warning than changing the browser settings.

Any other approach to solve this requirement is welcome, even if it might not be the answer I was looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're asking to evade IE's cross-site request security warning? Can't be done at the page level, only at the user level.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what do you mean by page & user level; but assume that it is not possible to prevent it at the client side, is it posible to read somehow the document from sharepoint site at the server-side and then re-stream it to the client; avoiding the cross-site request?

Comment: Page level: your web page. User level: user changes the security settings. You could probably proxy it if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google PDF viewer instead of asking the browser to load the PDF plugin.

**Update:** There are some security issues, no doubt.

- If your server is https and the google code is on http, then browser will throw an omnious warning. It will work though.
- Your users, if they have already logged into the Google account in the browser will have their PDF-reading habits recorded by Google.

Comment: I tried it before but I think I faced some issues related to security and stuff. I will look more into this too. Thanks